# Session ID keeps changing on navigating to other page WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, session, woocommerce

The current `session ID` keeps changing on every request.
I have a file called `session.php`.

It has this `php` code in it:

```
<?php

session_start();

$s_id = session_id();
print_r($s_id);

?>
```

Everytime I navigate to a other page this `ID` changes. How is this possible?

I disabled all plugins and has only this in my functions.php

```
<?php

function start_session() {
    if( !session_id() ) {
        session_start();
    }
}
add_action('init', 'start_session', 1);
```

Everytime I reload `datum.php` it shows a different `session id`.  On other WordPress sites it doesn't.

Comment: Can you post a few examples when you include this script?

Comment: How do you mean exactly?

Comment: I mean without seeing where (and more importantly, *when*) you include this script, it would be guesswork to determine the problem.

Comment: _Everytime I navigate to a other page this ID changes_ Do other pages have the same code?

Comment: You tagged this `wordpress` and `woocommerce` - so give us a proper explanation what the connection is here? Are you trying to use this _inside_ of WP somewhere, or are you deliberately calling this as a stand-alone script, circumventing WP?

Comment: I editted my question. I am only experiencing this on this site and on no other wordpress site

Answer (score 0):

First create a session_id. Then store it into session variable.
Next time check whether the session_id session value exits or not.
If exits then get the previous session id value from session.
otherwise create a new session id.

After complete your tasks (example logout) delete the session variable.

Comment: I editted my question. I am only experiencing this on this site and on no other wordpress site

Answer (score 0):

Method of start session in WordPress is something like below so check by updating your code first

```
function start_session() {
    if( !session_id() ) {
        session_start();
    }
}
add_action('init', 'start_session', 1);
```

Also if you want to use session for woocommerce then there also existing sessions for that as well which you may use it like

```
WC()->session->set( 'name_for_your_data' , $data );
WC()->session->get( 'name_for_your_data' );
```

More function and information about woocommerce session class here https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Session.html

Hope this help you to resolve your problem with session

Comment: I editted my question. I am only experiencing this on this site and on no other wordpress site